My OSL kit is having problem
Calibration using NA. I have problem calibrating my OSL kit.
First I will compenstate my path which from S11 to SMA to SMA cable - SMA to through connector and BMA to SMA connector. Afterwards I will calibrate my calibration kit which is connected at end of BMA to SMA connector. Next I will calibrate my Open Short Load connection using the pathway I previously mentioned above.
For load - reach above -30dBm which is my spec limit. How to tune it back?
For short I used 50 ohm termination.
USED CAL KIT (PESTR1001)
REFERENCE CAL KIT FOR COMPENSATE MY PATH LOSSES (85033E)

tune  back to what ?  Why 50 ohm for short test? Why deviate from OSL procedure?

6 month ago when i calibration the result is okay. i get -30dBm below which is good result. But now the result is bad im not sure whats happening

Redo OSL with best cable and verify. Then check for bad cables, connections , torque settings, contact damage.  Some Mods don't think this experience is design related.

Just tried to replace BMA - SMA connector and some LOAD kit are degrade im not sure why. I changed load with 50 ohm terminator.
